# Dual/Fourier Transform of Smooth Functions of Moderate Growth

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

If we consider $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ to be the space of compactly supported smooth functions (with the LF topology) and $\mathcal{E}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ to be the space of smooth functions with the Fréchet topology, then it is well known that if $
\cdot$ and $*$ represent multiplication and convolution, and $\mathcal{D}'$ is the space of distributions, $\mathcal{E'}$ is the space of compactly supported distributions, then
$$
u\in \mathcal{D}',\phi\in \mathcal{D}\implies u* \phi\in  \mathcal{E},
$$
$$
u\in \mathcal{D}',\phi\in \mathcal{D}\implies u\cdot \phi\in  \mathcal{E}'.
$$
The spaces $\mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{E}'$ are also related to $\mathcal{D}$, $\mathcal{D}'$ via
$$
u\in \mathcal{D}', v\in \mathcal{E}'\implies u* v\in \mathcal{D}'.
$$
$$
\phi\in \mathcal{D}, \psi\in \mathcal{E}\implies \phi\cdot \psi\in \mathcal{D}.
$$
If we replace $\mathcal{D}$ by $\mathcal{S}$, the space of Schwartz functions, I am curious about the existence of natural spaces $\mathcal{V}$, $\mathcal{W}$ (corresponding to $\mathcal{E},\mathcal{E}'$) large enough such that
$$
u\in \mathcal{S}',\phi\in \mathcal{S}\implies u* \phi\in \mathcal{V},
$$
$$
u\in \mathcal{S}',\phi\in \mathcal{S}\implies u\cdot \phi\in  \mathcal{W}.
$$
and small enough such that
$$
u\in\mathcal{S}', v\in\mathcal{W}\implies u*v\in\mathcal{S}'
$$
$$
\phi\in \mathcal{S}, \psi\in\mathcal{V}\implies u\cdot v\in\mathcal{S}
$$
I think that $\mathcal{V}$ should be "smooth functions of moderate growth" (this is proved in Stein and Shakarchi's *Functional Analysis*) and $\mathcal{W}$ should be "linear combinations of higher derivatives of rapidly decaying continuous functions" (based on the structure theorem for tempered distributions presented in Strichartz's *A Guide to Distribution Theory and Fourier Transforms* along with the fact that the distribution should be rapidly decaying). My questions are

1. Is this guess for characterizations of $\mathcal{V}$ and $\mathcal{W}$ are correct?
2. What is the natural topology for these spaces?
3. Is the dual of $\mathcal{V}$ identifiable with $\mathcal{W}$?
4. Is the Fourier transform a continuous isomorphism between these spaces? (or even continuous in one direction?)
5. What would be a good (online accessible preferred) reference for these sorts of questions.

**Edit:** Thanks for the recommendation to Horvath's "Topological Vector Spaces" it seems that to justify the relations (1), (3) and (4) one should use the spaces $\mathcal{V}=\mathcal{O}_C$, $\mathcal{W}=\mathcal{O}_C'$ and $\mathcal{V}=\mathcal{O}_M$. It seems that the image of Schwartz space multiplied by tempered distributions should be the space $\mathcal{U}$ of tempered distributions whose Fourier Transform lies in $\mathcal{O}_C$, and the space should have a final topology. An updated version of this question would be

1. Is there a nice characterization of $\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{O}_C)\subset \mathcal{S}'$, with $\mathcal{O}_C$ defined as in Horvath's *Topological Vector Spaces*? Does this space of distributions have a final topology as described in Ch 2.12?
2. Is the dual of this unknown space identifiable with $\mathcal{O}_M$?

Comment: You probably need the spaces $\mathscr{O}_{\rm M}$, $\mathscr{O}_{\rm C}$ and their duals. The best reference in French is the book Schwartz himself on distributions, and in English, it would be the book by Horvath "Topological Vector Spaces and Distributions, vol 1" (there is no vol. 2 BTW).

Comment: Thank you for the help. I couldn't seem to find a description of the Fourier Transform of the space O_C in Horvath. I have not conferred Schwartz's book as I cannot read French. Do you know if such a description is in this book, or available elsewhere?

Comment: $S'S$ should be the dual of  $\{ f\in C^\infty, fS\subset S\} = $ the smooth functions whose each derivative is bounded by a polynomial.

Comment: Thanks for the help @reuns , I agree that $\mathcal{S}’\mathcal{S}$ should be contained in the space you describe, which in the notation used by Horvath is $\mathcal{O}_M’$. I am wondering if this can be refined, as in $\mathcal{S}’\mathcal{S}\subset \mathcal{U}\subsetneq \mathcal{O}_M’$, where $\mathcal{U}$ is a space of distributions with a stronger topology so that $\mathcal{U}'=\mathcal{O}_M$ and the Fourier Transform is an isomorphism between $\mathcal{U}$ and $\mathcal{O}_C$. I don't like $\mathcal{O}_M'$ as the topology of $\mathcal{O}_M$ seems weak, so it's dual might be huge.

Comment: As an update, I see you are correct. For those who are curious for a reference, I found the following source very useful:   Larcher, Julian. "Multiplications and convolutions in L. Schwartz' spaces of test functions and distributions and their continuity" Analysis, vol. 33, no. 4, 2013, pp. 319-332. https://doi.org/10.1524/anly.2013.1200